# How can we use CryptoJS to verify signature?

Tags: javascript, cryptography, fingerprint, cryptojs

I am implementing biometric fingerprint auth as mentioned in the article https://itnext.io/biometrics-fingerprint-auth-in-your-web-apps-d5599522d0b3. In this article npm plugin `crypto` was used. But for some reason I can't use that in our application. So I am using `crypto-js`.

Below code is used to verify signature where we use node `crypto` plugin.

```
 const isVerified = crypto
    .createVerify("SHA256")
    .update(data)
    .verify(publicKey, signature);
```

How can we build the same signature verification using npm `crypto-js` plugin? I am ok using any other javascript library which does not use `crypto`.

Thanks

Comment: Signing/verifying isn't possible with CryptoJS. CryptoJS is a library for symmetric algorithms and not for asymmetric ones.

Comment: Does your Javascript code run in a browser ("Webcrypto" internal library) or Node JS ("crypto" internal library) ?

Comment: @Topaco Do you have any other suggestion what should I use?

Comment: @MichaelFehr This is for server side code. I can't use crypto due to some reason.

Comment: Library recommendations are off topic on SO.  Please try a Google search with NodeJS and the algorithm you are using, e.g. RSA or ECDSA.